# Decorators for recursion function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, decorator

I want to write a decorator that will compute runtime of function that compute fibonachi number of 5(fib(5)) 10 times and will print a medium runtime value. But my decorator returns an error. How to fix this problem?

```
import functools
import time

def trace(times):
    def cache(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            total = 0
            for i in range(times):
                start = time.time()
                func(*args, **kwargs)
                end = time.time()
                total += (end - start)
            print('Medium value is {}'.format(total / times))
            return func
        return wrapper
    return cache

@trace(times=10)
def fib(num):
    if num < 2:
        return num
    return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2)

fib(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of returning `func` in the `wrapper` return the result of it.

We have to make sure the tracing only happens for the first call to `fib` and none of the recursive calls. Let's use a boolean `traced` argument:

```
import functools
import time

def trace(times):
    def cache(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, traced=True, **kwargs):
            if not traced:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            total = 0
            for i in range(times):
                start = time.time()
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                end = time.time()
                total += (end - start)
                print(f'run {i}, time is {total}')
            print(f'Mean value is {total / times}')
            return result
        return wrapper
    return cache


@trace(times=10)
def fib(num, traced=True):
    if num < 2:
        return num
    return fib(num - 1, traced=False) + fib(num - 2, traced=False)


fib(5)
```

`traced` is `True` by default so any call to `fib(n)` will be traced (no need for user to be aware of the `traced` argument). However the recursive calls all have `traced=False` therefore they don't trigger the loop in the decorator.

Comment: but that program compute medium value for all of fib(5) - fib(5), fib(4), ..., fib(1). But I want just to compute medium value only for fib(5) 10 times. I want to print 10 values of fib(5) runtime

Comment: That's what I asked you in the comment above. Give me a moment...

Comment: Do you have to do it with decorators?

Comment: yes. with decorator

Comment: The difference between your code and my code is only 'traced', right?

Comment: Well I mean I `return result` not `func`, and I used f-string instead of `"".format()`

Comment: but `return result` and `return func(*args, **kwargs)` is the same thing because of `result = func(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243090/discussion-between-re-za-and-prostak).